# New question starts at -1?

Tags: support, down-votes

I just asked a new question, https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/300694/exact-php-syntax-for-dependency-injection . When I completed it and the view page loaded, its score was already -1. I'm pretty certain there was not enough time for anyone to downvote it. They would have had to have done so in the moment between me hitting 'Ask', and it loading for me right after that.

Is this a bug? Or is there something about my reputation or the question itself that would make it start out behind?

Comment: Some questions are clearly off-topic based on the title alone. That being said, one should definitely read the question before downvoting anyway because of what the down arrow text says: "this question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful." In order to measure that, one must read the question.

Comment: as @Snowman mentioned, if reader thought title is bad, they could vote in a split second, expecting that edit (if it happens) will let them revert anyway. In cases like that I still prefer to comment ASAP, [to avoid being trapped by grace period edits](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/251876/165773) but not everyone knows (or cares) about such tricky system details

Answer (score 4):

> I'm pretty certain there was not enough time for anyone to downvote it.

Well, you are wrong. :)

New questions pop up on in the news feed immediately, and there are enough people on the site for at least *someone* to see it very quickly indeed.

I find it more troubling that someone could have actually read and consider the question before downvoting it, mind you. Without knowing the actual timescales involved, I shan't comment further, but this does warrant *some* thought.

> Is this a bug?

Don't forget that post scores auto-update, so it may not have happened *quite* as quickly as you think. The post did not have to be at -1 at the moment you refreshed the page.

> Or is there something about my reputation or the question itself that would make it start out behind?

No; all questions and answers on Stack Exchange websites start life at 0 score.

Comment: I didn't refresh the page; it was on the first load after I submitted it : (

Comment: @user1936: Scores auto-update; it could have happened any time between submission and when you got around to looking at the score.

Comment: So I guess it can be that fast, and I'm happy to edit the question or remove it if warranted, I just wish people would comment so I could take appropriate action :/

Comment: @user1936: Yes: either way it would have been much better if the downvoter had taken some time to really properly read the question, and then to explain their downvote. I fully agree that the downvote is suspiciously fast (just not that it was automated).